When calling the TestInvokeAuthorizer operation: Missing Authentication Token
i have a custom authoriser which is linked to a lambda function which validates a jwt token using symmetric key , the lambda function event looks like this
{
"token": "MyToken"
}
the function works fine, now when i call the custom authoriser where signing is disabled , i get this error
An error occurred (MissingAuthenticationTokenException) when calling the TestInvokeAuthorizer operation: Missing Authentication Token
aws iot test-invoke-authorizer --authorizer-name sneha-test --token "MyToken" --no-sign-request --profile sneha
i have checked aws config and i have a sso session with profile name sneha from which i am connecting.
tried using reactjs code , same error.

sneha.jha were you able to resolve the issue? If so, what steps you took to fix it

Yes @UserJ I sent token as headers and turned signing off in authoriser
Sample cli cmd :
aws iot test-invoke-authorizer --authorizer-name sneha-test --http-context headers={'token'='TOKEN'}
